# How do I return a View and a Partial View to the Index Layout in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-6, partial-views

Both my home controller and my "StatusController" create a new instance of a DBEntities.  The Home Controller returns a _db.VMs ViewData.Model to the _Layout.cshtml view and the Status Controller returns a _db.Jobs ViewDataModel to the _GetForStatus.cshtml view as a partial view.  I call the VMs ViewData model to the _Layout view like so:

```
 @foreach (var m in ViewData.Model)
      {
           <li><a href="#">@m.Name</a></li>
      }
```

This works fine, populating the dropdown list with names of the VMs from the DB.
The _GetforStatus.
The Home Controller piece for this is written like so:

```
 public ActionResult index()
      {
           _db = new IntegrationDBEntitires();
           ViewData.Model = _db.VMs.ToList();
           return View();
      }
```

The StatusController is written like so:

```
 public PartialViewResult _GetforStatus()
      {
           _db = new OntegrationDBEntities();
           ViewData.Model = _db.Jobs.ToList();
           return PartialView();
      }
```

The _GetforStatus view is written like so:

```
 @model IntegrationWeb.Models.Job
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
           <div class="progress-bar" style="width: @((Model.IS_Progress / Model.IS_Total)*100)%"></div>
      </div>
 @Html.Action("_GetforStatus", "StatusController")
```

This is called in the _Layout view like so:\

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/_GetforStatus.cshtml")
```

I am getting an error here.  "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' 1[IntegrationWeb.models.VM]', but the dictionary requires model item type 'IntegrationWeb.Models.Job'.
It seems as though there is a conflict with pulling two different DBEntities into the Layout view.
How do I return a View and a Partial View to the Index Layout in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Update:  I just put the Action in the Home Controller, since I can't figure out why it won't find my Controller "StatusController".  Now I am getting a different error using @{Html.RenderAction("_GetforStatus");}   "The Model Item passed into the dictionary is type 'System.Collections.Generic.List '1[IntegrationWeb.models.Job]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'IntegrationWeb.models.Job'."  Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: show your  layout view and main view

Comment: What does `partialView()` do?  This is not a standard method...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  It is my understanding that it returns the partialview.

Comment: There is no method in MVC called partialView(), there is PartialView()... is this just a typo?

Comment: Yes, It is a typo.  I am rewritting from another computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partial view inherits the Model from the parent view, unless you specifically pass a property, or create another object to pass to it.  They are also processed of the same request.  So in your example, the controller action for the partial view isn't even being executed.  What you need to do instead is use RenderAction.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_GetforStatus","ControllerName"); }
```

This will then allow you to to execute a view with its own model and separate request.

Comment: Is that in the _Layout.cshtml view, the GetforStatus.cshtml view, or both?

Comment: I tried both and am getting error:  Server Error in '/' Application.  Compiler erroer message: CS1502.  Invalid Arguments.

Comment: That call can be in your layout view or the main/parent view.  Also note Html.RenderAction and Html.Action are very similar.  Html.Action returns a string, where as RenderAction outputs directly to the response stream and allows for better performance.  Not sure whats causing your compiler error.  Has any of your other code changed?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be finding my controller.  I wrote it this way in the _Layout shared view:  @Html.Action("StatusController",  //My controller name.  "_GetforStatus"  //The PartialViewResult action inside my controller.);  It isn't finding the path.

Comment: I just put the Action in the Home Controller, since I can't figure out why it won't find my Controller "StatusController".  Now I am getting a different error using @{Html.RenderAction("_GetforStatus");}   "The Model Item passed into the dictionary is type 'System.Collections.Generic.List '1[IntegrationWeb.models.Job]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'IntegrationWeb.models.Job'."

Comment: Your view _GetforStatus needs to declare @model List<IntegrationWeb.models.Job> since that is what you are setting the model equal to in the controller.

Comment: I did not have the "List> part around the model path, so I tried your suggestion, not I am getting a new error.  CS1061:"System.Collections.Generic.List<IntegrationWeb.Models.Job>' does not contain a definition for "IS_Progress" and no extension....

Comment: It sounds like in your _GetForStatus view you are trying to access Model.IS_Progress.  Since your view is using a list for the model, you need to access IS_Progress individually from each iterated item.  Try wrapping it in a @foreach(var item in Model) { <span>@item.IS_Progress</span> }

Comment: Thank you much!  Can you please give me an "up" on my question?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/_GetforStatus.cshtml")
```

simply do

```
@Html.Action("_GetForStatus", "MyController")
```

`Html.Partial` doesn't actually hit the action, it just renders the cshtml file.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error:  The controller path '/' was not found or does not implement IController  @Html.Action("_GetforStatus", "StatusController);